# How to set and get the value from the Object type variable in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Problem is how to set and get the value from the Object type variable. Here is the code:

```js
export interface AccountRequestInterface {
  additionalData: object;
}

export class PreferenceService {
  prepareRequest(Request: AccountRequestInterface): AccountRequestInterface {
    let request: AccountRequestInterface;
    var additionalData = {"consumerID": 123456} //Is this Correct?
    request.additionalData = additionalData;
    return request;
  }
  processResponse(eventType: EventType, response: AccountServiceResponseAdditionalDataInterface): void {
    let deummy= response.additionalData["consumerID"]; //Will deummy get the ConsumerID?
  }
}
```

In the above snippet I've got two functions `prepareRequest` and `processResponse`. In `prepareRequest` I've got to set the `"ConsumerID"` in `additionalData` which is of Object type and at `processResponse` I've got to get the value of `"ConsumerID"`. Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: Well, this is a low quality post and has too many missing parts and understanding of how TypeScript works. You should really start with typescript basics. Deummy will only get `ConsumerID` if response argument passed to `processResponse` has it. Also it's not clear what `AccountServiceResponseAdditionalDataInterface` is & how these functions are used.

Comment: @AliDemirci Thank you for quick response. Actually i want to store value in "additionalData(which is Object data type)" and get the value from "additionalData(which is Object data type)" that's it.

Comment: Types cannot have values. Instead, you can create a class, and then initialize it and pass it to the function as an argument.

Comment: It's still unclear where / how you're calling these functions and with what kind of information in it.